# Combine a column of dates with a column of times using chron package in R

Tags: r

I am combining some data to use the match() function to pull specific trade dates/times from a very large data frame and am completely stumped why my code is not working.  Notice that the Date and Time columns are separate, which has made a challenge for using the as.POSIXct function as well.  Please take a look:

This is how the data comes to me:

```
  Symbol      Date Time     Open     High      Low    Close Volume Tick.Count
1  USH94 01/3/1994 7:21 114.4062 114.4375 114.3750 114.4062      0          5
2  USH94 01/3/1994 7:22 114.3750 114.4062 114.3125 114.3750      0         11
3  USH94 01/3/1994 7:23 114.3438 114.3750 114.3125 114.3438      0          7
4  USH94 01/3/1994 7:24 114.3125 114.3125 114.2500 114.2812      0         14
5  USH94 01/3/1994 7:25 114.2500 114.2812 114.2188 114.2188      0          6
6  USH94 01/3/1994 7:26 114.1875 114.2500 114.1875 114.2500      0         13
```

I then use date() and time() function to convert the columns from factors to date and time values.  I also add seconds saved as a string in this case as variable a and I add an hour due to time changes.

```
US$Time <- times(paste(US$Time,a,sep = ':'))+1/24
US$Date <- dates(as.character(US$Date))
```

Here is what US looks like now:

```
head(US)

  Symbol     Date     Time     Open     High      Low    Close Volume Tick.Count
1  USH94 01/03/94 08:21:00 114.4062 114.4375 114.3750 114.4062      0          5
2  USH94 01/03/94 08:22:00 114.3750 114.4062 114.3125 114.3750      0         11
3  USH94 01/03/94 08:23:00 114.3438 114.3750 114.3125 114.3438      0          7
4  USH94 01/03/94 08:24:00 114.3125 114.3125 114.2500 114.2812      0         14
5  USH94 01/03/94 08:25:00 114.2500 114.2812 114.2188 114.2188      0          6
6  USH94 01/03/94 08:26:00 114.1875 114.2500 114.1875 114.2500      0         13
```

same.

Then I try to combine date and time with the paste() function

```
US$TradeDates <- paste(US$Date,US$Time)

head(US)

  Symbol     Date     Time     Open     High      Low    Close Volume Tick.Count        TradeDates
1  USH94 01/03/94 08:21:00 114.4062 114.4375 114.3750 114.4062      0          5 01/03/94 0.34791667
2  USH94 01/03/94 08:22:00 114.3750 114.4062 114.3125 114.3750      0         11 01/03/94 0.34861111
3  USH94 01/03/94 08:23:00 114.3438 114.3750 114.3125 114.3438      0          7 01/03/94 0.34930556
4  USH94 01/03/94 08:24:00 114.3125 114.3125 114.2500 114.2812      0         14 01/03/94 0.35000000
5  USH94 01/03/94 08:25:00 114.2500 114.2812 114.2188 114.2188      0          6 01/03/94 0.35069444
6  USH94 01/03/94 08:26:00 114.1875 114.2500 114.1875 114.2500      0         13 01/03/94 0.35138889
```

See that the TradeDates column has time in decimal form all of a sudden....but what is really stumpling me is that if I do the exact same function element by element I get the desired results:

```
US$TradeDates[1] <- paste(US$Date[1],US$Time[1])

head(US)

  Symbol     Date     Time     Open     High      Low    Close Volume Tick.Count          TradeDates
1  USH94 01/03/94 08:21:00 114.4062 114.4375 114.3750 114.4062      0          5   01/03/94 08:21:00
2  USH94 01/03/94 08:22:00 114.3750 114.4062 114.3125 114.3750      0         11 01/03/94 0.34861111
3  USH94 01/03/94 08:23:00 114.3438 114.3750 114.3125 114.3438      0          7 01/03/94 0.34930556
4  USH94 01/03/94 08:24:00 114.3125 114.3125 114.2500 114.2812      0         14 01/03/94 0.35000000
5  USH94 01/03/94 08:25:00 114.2500 114.2812 114.2188 114.2188      0          6 01/03/94 0.35069444
6  USH94 01/03/94 08:26:00 114.1875 114.2500 114.1875 114.2500      0         13 01/03/94 0.35138889
```

Notice the first row in the last column is exactly what I want, but all other rows are still in decimal form.  If this were a managable dataset I would just use a loop, but this is literally billions of rows and R simply cannot handle that loop.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What about `US$TradeDates <- chron(dates=US$Date, times=US$Time)`

Answer (score 1):

You should work in POSIX format, it would make your life easier.

You can convert the `Date` column to `POSIXlt` using

```
as.POSIXlt(as.character(US$Date), format="%d/%m/%Y")
```

Then, just add the `Time` column in seconds, and the `POSIXlt` format will handle the rest.